# How to prevent image from moving and stretching on zoom in/out on Grid Layout in CSS?

Tags: html, css, liquid

I created a grid layout template containing images like so:

[image]

However, when I zoom in and out, The images stretches on along its width when I zoom in and stretches out along its length when I zoom out.

My current html code is:

```
<div class="container">
   <figure class="gallery__item gallery-item-1">
      <img src="url" class="gallery__img">
   </figure>
   <figure class="gallery__item gallery-item-2">
      <img src="url" class="gallery__img">
   </figure>
   <figure class="gallery__item gallery-item-3">
      <img src="url" class="gallery__img">
   </figure>
   <figure class="gallery__item gallery-item-4">
      <img src="url" class="gallery__img">
   </figure>
```

This is my CSS

```
  .gallery__img {
      object-fit: fill;     
      width: 100%; 
      height: 100%;
  }
  .gallery__item--1 {
      grid-column-start: 1;
      grid-column-end: 6;
      grid-row-start: 1;
      grid-row-end: 12;
      margin-right: -35px;
      margin-top: -8px;
      overflow: hidden;
  }

  .gallery__item--2 {
      grid-column-start: 6;
      grid-column-end: 12;
      grid-row-start: 1;
      grid-row-end: 6;
      margin-right: -72px;
      margin-top: -8px;
      overflow: hidden;
  }

  .gallery__item--3 {
      grid-column-start: 6;
      grid-column-end: 9;
      grid-row-start: 6;
      grid-row-end: 12;
      margin-right: -55px;
      margin-top: -10px;
      overflow: hidden;
  }

  .gallery__item--4 {
      grid-column-start: 9;
      grid-column-end: 12;
      grid-row-start: 6;
      grid-row-end: 12;
      margin-left: 62px;
      margin-top: -10px;
      margin-right: -72px;
      overflow: hidden;
  }
```

Using this, the images stretch out but I managed to fix the stretch by setting the width and the height in the gallery image to auto. However, this moves my image element around when I zoom in our out like so:
[image]

How do I keep the grid layout while keep the aspect ratio of the image without stretching the images on zoom in or out? I also have some limitations. I cannot use libraries like Bootstrap as I am using it in Shopify which will cause some conflicts.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried setting a max height and a max width?

Comment: Should I add those to the parent class? or to individual images class?